# Always getting FileNotFoundException in java

Tags: java, file-io

I am using `Scanner` to read the File contents. For that I am using the following code.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("/File.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        // Until the end
        System.out.print(sc.nextLine());
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

But this code always throws `FileNotFoundException`. I have tried Googling this, but I can't find where to check the file. Secondly, I have created files with same name in almost every directory to check when would the Code catch the presence of file.

[image]

You can see in the Package I have created a file named **File.txt** so that code can find it whereever it looks for.

In the Java docs, I get to know that the File accepts a String parameter as

```
File file = new File("file_name");
```

But what sort or what would be the param here, isn't told. Can I get the help?

Comment: @ZouZou, yes that was the error. Can I get to know, why Slash causes the trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `File file = new File("File.txt");` instead of `File file = new File("/File.txt");`, get rid of the slash. If what you want is a relative path, you want `.\File.txt`

As @deterministicFail says in the comments, it is not a good idea to hardcode path separators, instead use `System.getProperty("path.separator");` This way your code should work in multiple plataforms, so your code would be:

To make it plataform independent (Asuming you are using a relative path):

```
File file = new File("." + System.getProperty("path.separator") + "File.txt");
```

Comment: What would be the error by Slash sign? Because this does work! :) I mean why does Slash sign generate the error? Some sort of File Directory issue ? Can I know what?

Comment: The slash is not a character allowed in filenames in Linux, and I think in windows neither. As @Mati Cicero says, if you want to put a path to open the file you should use `\path\to\file`. And if the path is relative, you want `.\File.txt`

Comment: +1 thanks alot brother. :) I appreciate your help for me. I will use back slashes from now on. :)

Comment: dont use slash or backslash use this: System.getProperty("path.separator");
and have a look at
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: @deterministicFail thanks, I've update the answer, I wanted to make it simple, but you have a point, it is better to use `getProperty`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
File file = new File("/File.txt");
```

with

```
File file = new File(".\\File.txt");
```

or

```
File file = new File("File.txt");
```

Comment: you mean `".\\File.txt"`.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done it the way you did but this is how I read files.

This is the purpose of the class `FileInpuStream`. I use a buffer to get bytes.

If it is only  a problem of path, why don't you simply use the complete path ? You can copy paste it from the file information.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

 public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  FileInputStream fis = null; 

  try {
  // object I use to read files
     fis = new FileInputStream(new File("File.txt"));
     byte[] buf = new byte[8];

     int n = 0;

 // while there is something in the file
     while ((n = fis.read(buf)) >= 0) {            
        for (byte bit : buf) {
           // do what you want
           System.out.print("\t" + bit + "(" + (char) bit + ")");
           System.out.println("");
        }
     }


  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {

     e.printStackTrace();
  } 
     try {
        if (fis != null)
           fis.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

  }
```

}
}

Comment: Please explain your code. It is not that useful at the moment and could be deleted.

Comment: It is better now. Good job !

Answer (score 0):

```
File f=new File("testFile.txt");
```

For this kind of referral you need to put file in root of your eclipse project (In parallel of src). This problem is only when you are Using Eclipse IDE.

[image: Screen shot for test file]

Best solution for this kind of problems is checking AbsolutePath of the file

```
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

It will give you path where your code is looking for file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities if you are looking for the file in the working directory then either use "File.txt" or "./File.txt". In case of windows one more option would be to use ".\File.txt).

If that is not what you are looking for, you can check which path the file refers to using either of the two sysouts immediately after instantiating the file, which will give you the absolute path on your machine.
    `File f = new File("/File.txt");`
    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(f.getAbsoluteFile().getAbsolutePath());

Answer (score -1):

Try not to use the **/** in **File.txt**, and if you really have to, use the backslash instead **\** since you're in Windows